# More swing design & actions

Tags: java, design-patterns, swing

Im pretty new to gui programming so i've been reading through every post on this site about swing and design. Whats been answered over and over again is that one should have a multiton class for the actions. Like this: (`GUI` being some `JFrame`)

[alt text http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/255/skjermdump.png](http://img341.imageshack.us/img341/255/skjermdump.png)

Now, this works great for one-way actions, like OpenDialog. But the actions for buttons in `DialogA` and `B` will have to have access to all the components (there will be many) in its dialog, and the `controller`. This is where im stuck.

The only sane way i can see is to put it in `DialogA/B` *but* i would then need to pass the `controller` all the way down, through classes that dont even need it, and it'll get all spaghetti. Really dont want that.

Someone must have encountered this problem before. So where should i put this `Action`? Or should i just drop the whole design?

**Edit:** got a good answer from elsewhere. Resolved.

Comment: Can you be more specific?  I'm not able to understand this design or what you are trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: @takoi I cannot see the image. If it is code post it here or if it is something else [upload it using the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28496851/how-to-upload-pictures-to-stackoverflow-for-posting)

Answer (score 1):

In MVC the controller and the view access each other, the controller shields the view from the model. The best thing to do is to put your ActionHandler as anonymous class and have it simply call back to your view that in turn calls the controller.
If you really want you could have a Controller superclass that has generic messages to send a message and pass in a HashMap, that gives you good separation of code but, adds complexity and removes type checking.